# C++ Netbeans Connecting to MySQL giving error

Tags: c++, mysql

I am trying to create a C++ program on netbeans( and on win 7) that connects to a MySQL server.I'm using the library's that i got from MySQL

```
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <mysql_connection.h>


int SQLConnection(){

sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;

driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "password");
delete con;
}
```

But i keep getting this error.

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Renier.SOFTWARESOL/Documents /NetBeansProjects/TestOne'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/testone.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Renier.SOFTWARESOL/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestOne'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/MySQLConnect.o.d
g++    -c -g -I../../../../../MySQL/Connector\ C++\ 1.1.0/include -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/MySQLConnect.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/MySQLConnect.o MySQLConnect.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/testone build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/ISP.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/WorkDone.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Individual.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Domain.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Employee.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Device.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Computer.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/ThreeG.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Line.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Software.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/MySQLConnect.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Site.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/LogMethod.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Request.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Network.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Email.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/runner.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/MAC.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Router.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Company.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Status.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/ThreeGModem.o -L../../../../../MySQL/Connector\ C++\ 1.1.0/lib -L../../../../../MySQL/MySQL\ Server\ 5.5/lib -lmysql -lmysqlcppconn-static 
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:83: recipe for target `dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/testone.exe' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Renier.SOFTWARESOL/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestOne'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:80: recipe for target `.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Renier.SOFTWARESOL/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestOne'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target `.build-impl' failed
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/MySQLConnect.o: In function `get_mysql_driver_instance':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Renier.SOFTWARESOL/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestOne/../../../../../MySQL/Connector C++ 1.1.0/include/mysql_driver.h:87: undefined reference to `sql::mysql::get_driver_instance()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/testone.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 12s)
```

Any advise?

Comment: Not related to the error, but you are deleting `con` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to make a raw compile of this? put into the linker mysqlcppconn.lib !

```
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

int main(){

sql::Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;
sql::Statement *stmt;
sql::ResultSet *res;
sql::Statement *pstmt;

try{
driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("localhost", "root", "root");
con->setSchema("test");
stmt = conn->createStatement();

/*blah blah yada yada*/

}catch(sql::SQLException &e){
    std::cout<<e.what();
}
```

Comment: Thank your for the reply. I got a wall of red text after i ran it.

This is one of the lines of code
Warning: resolving _mysql_stmt_store_result@4 by linking to _mysql_stmt_store_result

Comment: you need to install the mysql library, have you installed it?

Comment: Yes i have Installed and linked the libraries that i found for mysql

Comment: get_mysql_driver_instance --> This indicates that the libmysqlcpp is not installed or not included when linking. In addition i recommend to try this statement "con = driver->connect("localhost", "user", "password");" , 3306 is the default port anyway and tcp the default protocol. Maybe the question would also be, is the this "new" error _mysql_stmt_store_result or did it appear after you have linked the library